# In what situations are the parameters used to instantiate a template are not available?

Tags: c++, templates, traits

In this article [Traits: a new and useful template technique](http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html) ,traits was introduced traits in C++ first time, and the author emphasized the following:

```
template <class numT>
class matrix {
public:
  typedef numT num_type;
  typedef float_traits<num_type> traits_type;
  inline num_type epsilon() { return traits_type::epsilon(); }
  ...
};
```

Notice that in all the examples thus far, each template provided public `typedef`s of its parameters, and also anything that depended on them. **This is no accident: in a wide variety of situations, the parameters used to instantiate a template are not available, and can only be retrieved if provided as `typedef`s in the template declaration.** The moral: always provide these `typedefs`.

But what confuses me is that no situation is shown where using the `typedef` would be necessary. Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example:

---

Consider you wanted to write a generic ***sum*** function that sums all elements in an ***`STL container`***. This can be *`vector`*, *`list`* or *`set`*. And the contents might be *`int`*'s, *`float`*'s or *`string`*'s (*for strings sum will be concatenation*)(to keep it simple).

If the container contains *`int`*'s then the sum will be *`int`*. If it contains *`floats`* then the sum will not be an *`int`* but you a *`floating`* point. And for *`strings`* it should be a *`string`*. Everyhing else is the same (*the operations inside the function.*)

---

One way to write this will be

```
template<typename T>
T sum(const vector<T>& t) {
   T total = T();
   // iterate and sum.
   return total;
}
```

but the problem is that now you need to write this function for each container type (*`set`*, *`list`*,..). So it is not really that generic.

---

To be more generic you will need to write something like this

```
template<typename T>
?? sum(const T& t) {
   ?? total;
   // iterate and sum.
   return ??
}
```

but what to return here?. How will you know what the container contains. Here is where the **`typedefs`** come in. **Lucky STL containers have a couple of typedefs that can give you some insights to what they do and are capable of doing**. For our case they defined the contained type as ***`value_type`*** (*I am sure you have used `C::iterator` at some point which is also a typedef*).

---

Now our little sum function can be written as

```
template<typename T>
typename
T::value_type sum(const T& t) {
   typedef typename T::value_type v_type;;
   v_type total = v_type();
   // iterate and sum.
   return total;
}
```

---

Generally it is a good idea to forward your template types with *`typdefs`*. For example if you are designing a template class *`C`* with two template types *`T`* and *`V`*

```
template<typename T, typename V>
class C {
    typedef T t_type;
    typedef V v_type;
    //
    //
}
```

This will be useful for someone else using *`C`*. They can easily find with what types *`T`* and *`V`* did an object *`c`* of type *`C`* get typed.

Comment: +1, but your uses of `value_type` require `typename` because they are template dependent type names. (Example without typename: http://ideone.com/JVBlBy ; example with: http://ideone.com/EbCbr1 )

Comment: (Erm my examples suck because I didn't initialize total; oh well)

Comment: @BillyONeal :D OK. Just trying to show the minimum. Sometimes people need just a simple example. Only to show the theory. But I will fix that too. Thank you. The reason I wrote it in the first place was not to copy you but because yours seemed a little to complicated for a beginner.

Comment: @BillyONeal I have noticed this probelm on SO. Someone asks a very basic question and people start giving him all kinds of fancy implementation which end up confusing the OP. Sometimes less is more.

Comment: @user: Yes, I understand that. But if one gives an example which looks like it should compile to a beginner, and it doesn't, the beginner is often left confused. Where possible code should at least compile even if it doesn't do anything useful :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a function template that accepts a generic container of `T`:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
void DoThings(ContainerT const& input)
{
   // Do something
}
```

In this method, you want to get an iterator to something in the container. But you don't know the iterator's type; you've only been given the type of the container, not the iterator:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
void DoThings(ContainerT const& input)
{
   /* ??? */ it = input.begin();
}
```

Let's say for the sake of argument that you could solve that problem, and you wanted to dereference the iterator. To store the result, you need to know what `T` is; but that causes the same problem again:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
void DoThings(ContainerT const& input)
{
   /* ??? */ it = input.begin();
   /* ??? */ firstElement = *it;
}
```

We don't know what `T`, the type contained in the container is; we only have the type of the container itself in this function template. In order to get the type inside the container we need the container to help us out a little bit and tell us what its contained type is. The container class does that via `typedef`s. For the standard containers, this would be `iterator` for the iterator type, and `value_type` for the contained value type:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
void DoThings(ContainerT const& input)
{
   // Container provides its iterator type via a typedef.
   typename ContainerT::iterator it = input.begin();

   // Container provides its contained type via a typedef.
   typename ContainerT::value_type firstElement = *it;
}
```

Even in C++11, where you could solve the above example with `auto`:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
void DoThings(ContainerT const& input)
{
   // Make the compiler figure it out:
   auto it = input.begin();
   auto firstElement = *it;
}
```

sometimes you still want to be able to get the actual type for other purposes:

```
// Failure to compile: http://ideone.com/vxJ2IU
// Successful compile: http://ideone.com/b5fU3S
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ContainerT>
void DoThings(ContainerT const& input)
{
   // DoThings only accepts integral containers:
   static_assert(
      std::is_integral<typename ContainerT::value_type>::value,
      "DoThings requires that the contained type be integral");
   // Make the compiler figure it out:
   auto it = input.begin();
   auto firstElement = *it;
   std::cout << firstElement;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> abc;
    abc.push_back(42);

    std::list<long> def;
    def.push_back(1729);

    std::deque<short> queue;
    queue.push_back(1234);

    DoThings(abc);
    DoThings(def);
    DoThings(queue);

    // Does not compile due to static assert:
    std::vector<double> doubles;
    doubles.push_back(3.14);
    DoThings(doubles);
}
```